# json.load agony to create dictionary instead of list

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

I have a python script which grabs data from a site in json:

```
channels_json = json.loads(url)
```

the site returns data as follows:

```
[ { '1': 'http://ht.co/bbda24210d7bgfbbbbcdfc2a023f' },
{ '2': 'http://ht.co/bbd10d7937932965369c248f7ccdfc2a023f' },
{ '3': 'http://ht.co/d3a01f6e5e74eb2cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
{ '4': 'http://ht.co/56d3a01f6e5e72cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
{ '5': 'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc447b99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },
{ '6': 'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc44bb99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },
....]
```

The problem is that Python is making this into a list rather than a dictionary.  So I can't reference '4' like this:

```
print (channels_json["4"])
```

and get the response:

```
http://ht.co/56d3a01f6e5e72cb5840556d80a52adf2871d
```

Instead Python spits out:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

If I run this code:

```
for c in channels_json:
   print c
```

Python prints out each set of coupled data like this:

```
{u'1': u'http://ht.co/bbda24210d7bgfbbbbcdfc2a023f' },
{ u'2': u'http://ht.co/bbd10d7937932965369c248f7ccdfc2a023f' },
{ u'3': u'http://ht.co/d3a01f6e5e74eb2cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
{ u'4': u'http://ht.co/56d3a01f6e5e72cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
{ u'5': u'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc447b99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },
{ u'6': u'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc44bb99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },
```

How can I get the above into a dictionary so I can reference value '6' as a string and get back

```
http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc44bb99c9ce609916ccf931f16a
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Seems like a simple case of iterating over the list and adding the internal dicts to a single dict one at a time.

Comment: The readon why you are getting the error ( in my opinion ) is that you are trying to access the elemnt using key in the array ( list ) which is impossible , try to do my_link = link[4] and then my_link["5"] ( arrays starts at 0!!  )

Comment: Use `channels_json = json.loads(url)[0]` if your list contains only one item.

Comment: Every time I attempt to get the value from the list by referring to values in the array (as suggested below) I get `value NameError: name 'value' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the dictionary you want by iterating over the dictionaries in the `list` returned from `json.load()` as shown below:

```
#json_data = json.loads(url)

json_data = [{ '1': 'http://ht.co/bbda24210d7bgfbbbbcdfc2a023f' },
             { '2': 'http://ht.co/bbd10d7937932965369c248f7ccdfc2a023f' },
             { '3': 'http://ht.co/d3a01f6e5e74eb2cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
             { '4': 'http://ht.co/56d3a01f6e5e72cb5840556d80a52adf2871d' },
             { '5': 'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc447b99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },
             { '6': 'http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc44bb99c9ce609916ccf931f16a' },]

# Convert to single dictionary.    
channels_json = dict(d.popitem() for d in json_data)

print(json.dumps(channels_json, indent=4))  # Pretty-print result.
```

Output:

```
{
    "1": "http://ht.co/bbda24210d7bgfbbbbcdfc2a023f",
    "2": "http://ht.co/bbd10d7937932965369c248f7ccdfc2a023f",
    "3": "http://ht.co/d3a01f6e5e74eb2cb5840556d80a52adf2871d",
    "4": "http://ht.co/56d3a01f6e5e72cb5840556d80a52adf2871d",
    "5": "http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc447b99c9ce609916ccf931f16a",
    "6": "http://ht.co/9ed0bb4cc44bb99c9ce609916ccf931f16a"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dd = {}

 for d in c:
     for key, value in d.items():
         dd[key] = value
```

Comment: Getting closer but this spits out `for key, value in d.items():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the array and build your dictionary

```
channels_json = {}
channels_array = json.loads(url)
for d in channels_array:
    key = list(d.keys())[0]
    val = d[key]
    channels_json[key] = val
```

Now you should be able to reference your dictionary `channels_json`

Comment: I am just curiouse ... how can that work ? What is d.keys() good for ???

Comment: `d.keys()` returns all the keys in the dictionary. So if you only have 1 key, then just select the 0th index

Comment: Thx for clarifing it ^^

Comment: Thanks for the response but that just kicks out the following error:  `channels_json[key] = value
NameError: name 'value' is not defined`

Comment: @manners What error did you get ? I tried it. It worked perfectly

Comment: Note I'm having to use `json.load` not `json.loads`.  If I use `json.loads` I get this error  `obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: I am not sure about the json loading part, but I started from the assumption that `channels_json` is an array as you have mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic way of doing this.

```
channels = {}
for i in json.loads(url): channels.update(i)
```

or

```
channels = {}
[channels.update(i) for i in json.loads(url)]
```

In both cases the dictionary gets updated with your list of separate dictionaries.